# Change the style of a tag that is only in wanted elements

Tags: css

So i have a page like this :

```
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><span class="first">First</span></li>
        <li><span class="second">Second</span></li>
        <li><span class="third">Third</span></li>
        <li><span class="fourth">Fourth</span></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

I want to change the style of the "li" tags that are only in the first and the second span.

I tried this `.first,.second li{margin-left:10px;}`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid...`li`  can only be children of a `ul`. **Validate your code**

Comment: @Paulie_D ... or of an `ol`

Comment: @PaulL Well yes, but the point is made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comma needs to separate COMPLETE element paths:

```
.first  li, .second li
{margin-left:10px;}
```

I've wasted enough time explaining why I didn't mention your improper formatting that I might as well correct you on it at this point;

```
<body>
    <ul>
        <li class="first">First</li>
        <li class="second">Second</li>
        <li class="third">Third</li>
        <li class="fourth">Fourth</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
li.first, li.second {
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

If we're really going to travel down this rabbit hole and teach code, might as well mention this can be done entirely without classes:

```
ul li:nth-child(1), ul li:nth-child(2)
{
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Don't recall saying anything of the such.

Comment: @Paulie_D If you want to make a comment to the such, I encourage you to do so, but this is an answer, an answer to a question. The user asked a question, I provided an answer, nothing more/less. If the user wants to run the code through a validator and has questions as to why encapsulating LI elements inside other containers is taboo then I will answer THAT question.

Comment: @Paulie_D For that matter if I really cared, I would ask "Why not just apply the class directly to the LI element?".

Comment: @Paulie_D, I might refer to it as more of tough love, if a dev isnt going to care enough to validate code, why should I waste breath trying to teach him how he **should** code. SO is FULL of examples of poorly written code, I'd go mad if I tried to teach everybody everything.

Comment: @Paulie_D I dont disagree, if you have the patience to do so. But **not** doing so when there is a very precise question and ugly or even improper code has no bearing on the solution, isn't  wrong per say.

Answer (score -3):

The `li` has to follow each parent element, you can't group the parents together and then expect the child to apply to each of them.  What you were asking for is for the style to apply to all `li` that are children of elements with `class=second`, and to all elements with `class=first`, not to all `li` that are children of elements with `class=first`

```
.first li, .second li { margin-left:10px }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/udnjqqkh/

Comment: Correcting the HTML is important...don't you think?

Answer (score -5):

.first  li {margin-left:10px;}
.second li {margin-left:10px;}

Comment: What does this add to previous answers given several minutes ago?